# Conditionally running transform on browserify

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify

I have added the babelify transformation and i've noticed that my mainScripts task now takes around 10 seconds instead of 0.5s as before.

I would therefore like to apply **.transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015"]})** only when the environment is or prod in order to speed up the task during development.

**My function for determining the current environment**

```
var isLocal = function() {
  return argv.env === 'localdev' || argv.env === 'dev';
};
```

**My scripts task:**

```
 gulp.task('mainScripts', function() {
      return browserify('./app/app.js', {
          debug: true
        })
        .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015"]})
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function(err) {
          console.log(err.toString());
          this.emit("end");
        })
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(gulpif(!condition, sourcemaps.init({
          loadMaps: true
        })))
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())
        .pipe(gulpif(!condition, uglify({
          mangle: true
        }).on('error', gutil.log)))
        .pipe(gulpif(!condition, sourcemaps.write('./')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/')).
         pipe(gulpif(isLocal(), connect.reload()));
    });
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `browserify` returns the bundler and the `transform` call is just chained off that, so you can optionally call `transform` by doing something like this:

```
gulp.task('mainScripts', function() {
  var bundler = browserify('./app/app.js', {
    debug: true
  });
  if (!isLocal()) {
    bundler = bundler.transform("babelify", { presets: ["es2015"] });
  }
  return bundler
    .bundle()
    .on('error', function(err) {
      ...
    }
    ...
```

Alternatively, you could have a look for some gulp recipes for [`watchify`](https://github.com/substack/watchify), which should greatly improve your incremental build times.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `.plugin`?

```
var babelify = function (b) {
  return isLocal()
    ? b
    : b.transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015"]});
};

// .plugin(babelify)
```

browserify [Plugins](https://github.com/browserify/browserify#plugins) section says: plugin `take the bundle instance as their first parameter`

> For some more advanced use-cases, a transform is not sufficiently extensible. Plugins are modules that take the bundle instance as their first parameter and an option hash as their second.

Applying plugin will be formatted like this:

```
var babelify = function (b) {
  return isLocal()
    ? b
    : b.transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015"]});
};

gulp.task('mainScripts', function() {
     return browserify('./app/app.js', {
         debug: true
       })
       .plugin(babelify)
       .bundle()
       .on('error', function(err) {
         ...
       }
       ...
```